# How to fix a problem showing "program linking failed" in flutter and crashes the App

Tags: flutter

Whenever i pressed the Run code for my flutter app it shows "Program linking failed" in the debugging section...But the problem lies when i press the submit button which i designed in the flutter UI it crashes the App. 
I tried uninstalling the app and reinstalled it ..but it keep happening.
Used both emulator and hardware phone.
Using latest flutter version.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
I/flutterpractis( 6194): Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/flutterpractis( 6194): Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
I/flutterpractis( 6194): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/        ( 6194): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe1592500, tid 6255
D/EGL_emulation( 6194): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe74d16e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe1583330)
D/skia    ( 6194): Program linking failed.
I/chatty  ( 6194): uid=10088(com.example.flutterpractise) 1.gpu identical 9 lines
D/skia    ( 6194): Program linking failed.
D/skia    ( 6194): Program linking failed.
I/chatty  ( 6194): uid=10088(com.example.flutterpractise) 1.gpu identical 3 lines
D/skia    ( 6194): Program linking failed.
D/skia    ( 6194): Program linking failed.


After i pressed the submit button...


E/flutter ( 6194): [ERROR:flutter/third_party/txt/src/minikin/FontFamily.cpp(184)] Could not get cmap table size!
E/flutter ( 6194): 
E/flutter ( 6194): [ERROR:flutter/third_party/txt/src/minikin/FontFamily.cpp(184)] Could not get cmap table size!
E/flutter ( 6194): 
F/flutter ( 6194): [FATAL:flutter/third_party/txt/src/minikin/FontCollection.cpp(95)] nTypefaces == 0
F/libc    ( 6194): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 6254 (1.ui), pid 6194 (flutterpractise)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:9/PSR1.180720.075/5124027:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 6194, tid: 6254, name: 1.ui  >>> com.example.flutterpractise <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/third_party/txt/src/minikin/FontCollection.cpp(95)] nTypefaces == 0
'
    eax 00000000  ebx 00001832  ecx 0000186e  edx 00000006
    edi 00001832  esi 00000060
    ebp cb6cc0c8  esp cb6cc068  eip ebf9eb39
backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000b39  [vdso:ebf9e000] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
    #01 pc 0001fdf8  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
    #02 pc 00022ed3  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+115)
    #03 pc 00bddc8a  /data/app/com.example.flutterpractise-DT0vCEIyC2uVyZUybDCb5w==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0xb97000)
    #04 pc 00e5969f  /data/app/com.example.flutterpractise-DT0vCEIyC2uVyZUybDCb5w==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0xb97000)
    #05 pc 00e5c94d  /data/app/com.example.flutterpractise-DT0vCEIyC2uVyZUybDCb5w==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0xb97000)
    #06 pc 00e5d351  /data/app/com.example.flutterpractise-DT0vCEIyC2uVyZUybDCb5w==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0xb97000)
    #07 pc 00c00388  /data/app/com.example.flutterpractise-DT0vCEIyC2uVyZUybDCb5w==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0xb97000)
    #08 pc 00bfdcd4  /data/app/com.example.flutterpractise-DT0vCEIyC2uVyZUybDCb5w==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0xb97000)
    #09 pc 00bfd273  /data/app/com.example.flutterpractise-DT0vCEIyC2uVyZUybDCb5w==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0xb97000)
    #10 pc 01036a57  /data/app/com.example.flutterpractise-DT0vCEIyC2uVyZUybDCb5w==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0xb97000)
    #11 pc 010369b0  /data/app/com.example.flutterpractise-DT0vCEIyC2uVyZUybDCb5w==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0xb97000)
    #12 pc 00000957  <anonymous:cb240000>
Application finished.
```

Comment: Add some code in post

Comment: dunno if this helps but try `flutter clean`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and `flutter clean` worked

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

https://mehraban.com.au/2018/11/16/how-to-fix-vscode-flutter-debug/

Maybe this can help. You can create the Json file or run this on the CLI:

Flutter run --enable-software-rendering --profile

Answer (score -2):

Check the fonts section in `pubspec.yaml` file and define the style for the custom fonts you use in the application.
the issue arises due to the `type-face` not defined for custom fonts